# Duda dobre JTables y ScrollPane

Tags: java, jtable

Buenas necesito ayuda con mi código, no me funciona `ScrollPane`.

Cuando lo intento aplicar en un método y añadirle un `jTable`, me salta el siguiente **error**:

> "JTable cannot be converted to int".

Este es mi código:

```
public void llenarTabla(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
    DefaultTableModel tmodelo = new DefaultTableModel();
    JTable tabla = new JTable(tmodelo);

    ResultSetMetaData mdata = rs.getMetaData();
    int numCols = mdata.getColumnCount();
    String[] columnas = new String[numCols];
    for (int i = 0; i < numCols; i++) {
        columnas[i] = mdata.getColumnName(i + 1);
    }
    tmodelo.setColumnIdentifiers(columnas);

    if (rs.next()) {
        String[] filas = new String[numCols];
        for (int i = 0; i < numCols; i++) {
            filas[i] = rs.getString(i + 1);
        }
        tmodelo.addRow(filas);
    }
    ScrollPane scroll = new ScrollPane(tabla);
    this.vista.add(scroll);
}
```

Comment: Que es lo que quieres hacer con el `ScrollPane`

Comment: Mi problema es que no se vIsualizan los nombre de las columnas en el JTable.